# awk shrinks multiple spaces to one

Tags: awk

I'm trying to get rid of the first column using awk. If I assign empty string to first column then all other spaces inside another columns are shrinked to one space. How to disable space shrinking?

```
$ echo 'a   b   c' | awk '{print $0}'
a   b   c

$ echo 'a   b   c' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
 b c
```

I'm using stadard awk inside ubuntu repo

```
$ dpkg -l | grep awk
ii  mawk                                  1.3.3-17ubuntu3                                  amd64    a pattern scanning and text processing language
```

Comment: When you modify any column in `awk` i.e. `$1=""` you force awk to reformat a record using default `OFS` which is just a single space.

Answer (score 1):

When you modify any field in `awk` i.e. `$1=""` you **force** `awk` to reformat a record using default `OFS`, which is just a single space.

Having said that, one way in `awk` to remove first column while preserving whitespaces between fields is:

```
echo 'a   b   c' | awk '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+/, "")} 1'
```

```
b   c
```

Or if you're using `gnu-awk` then use:

```
echo 'a   b   c' | awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]+' 'NR > 1{ORS=RT; print}'
```

```
b   c
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) array *slice*:

```
echo 'a   b   c' | perl -lane 'print join "\t", @F[1..2]'
```

### Output

```
b   c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'a   b   c' | awk '{print substr($0,index($0,FS)+1)}'
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` might be easier

```
$ echo 'a   b   c' | sed -E 's/\S+\s+//'
b   c
```